# Calculus 2 problem

Tags: integration

evaluate the indefinite integral,

$$ \int \frac{5x-3x^{2}-17}{(x - 1)(x^2+4)} \ dx . $$

I found $ -3 \ln(x-1)+\frac{5}{2x}\ln(x^2+4)+C $ but apparently that isn't correct

Comment: Your partial fraction decomposition looks to be correct; you should have been left with a second-term integral $ \int \ \frac{5}{x^2 + 4} \ dx \ , $ giving the second term **Rana** shows below. [Now I see what your form means: the anti-derivative is not found by treating the integrand as $ \ (x^2 + 4)^{-1} \ $ and using logarithms,  as taking the derivative will show.]

Answer (score 1):

The answer is $$-3ln(x-1)+\frac{5}{2}\tan^{-1}\frac{x}{2}+c$$ since $$\int\frac{5}{x^2+4} dx=\frac{5}{2}\tan^{-1}\frac{x}{2}$$